# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'configure'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm pretty new to python and Tkinter. I want to create 6 buttons and when you click on one of the buttons, the button text changes. I'm getting this error:  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'configure'`.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

b1 = Button(root, text = '', width = 10, height = 5, command = lambda: main(1))
b1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
b2 = Button(root, text = '', width = 10, height = 5, command = lambda: main(2))
b2.grid(row = 0, column = 2)
b3 = Button(root, text = '', width = 10, height = 5, command = lambda: main(3))
b3.grid(row = 0, column = 3)
b4 = Button(root, text = '', width = 10, height = 5, command = lambda: main(4))
b4.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
b5 = Button(root, text = '', width = 10, height = 5, command = lambda: main(5))
b5.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
b6 = Button(root, text = '', width = 10, height = 5, command = lambda: main(6))
b6.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

def main(num):
    something = 'b' + str(num)
    something.configure(text = 'hi')
```

I did this before so maybe there is a small mistake I made.
Thx in advance!

Comment: I would recommend that you put all of the buttons in a list but you can just replace `something.configure(text = 'hi')` with `globals()[something].configure(text="hi")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to create a vairable name by making a string.

So your variable 'something' ends up being "b2" for example which isn't the variable b2.

There's a couple of ways you could do this, one would be put your variables into a dict.

```
buttons = {'b2': Button(root, text='', width=10, height=5, command=lambda: main(1))}
# or like this once buttons is declared as a dict
buttons['b2'] = Button(root, text='', width=10, height=5, command=lambda: main(1))
```

Then to access the buttons you would do

```
buttons['b2'].grid(row = 0, column = 1)
buttons['b2'].configure(text = 'hi')
```

A faster way as suggested by TheLizzard (I've not tested it)

```
buttons = []
buttons.append(Button(root, text='', width=10, height=5, command=lambda: main(1)))
```

Then access by

```
buttons[0].grid(row=0, column=1)
```

I guess it is faster but maybe if you're dealing with lots of buttons having a readable key value could win out over performance?

Comment: Wouldn't a list be better? It is faster to index and it makes more sense for all of the buttons to be in a list.